# Как добавить атрибут open к <details> в компьютерной версии сайта?

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы к `<details>` в компьютерной версии добавлялся атрибут `open`, то есть чтобы спойлер был по умолчанию открыт для ПК-версии и закрыт для мобильной версии. Это можно сделать только на CSS?

Comment: Для таких случаев есть JavaScript, не совсем уверен, что такое делается через CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя добавлять атрибуты HTML-элементам через CSS, только JavaScript. Для этого подойдёт следующий код, взятый с вопроса на [Хабре](https://qna.habr.com/q/277777):

```
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // код для мобильных устройств
}
else {
// код для обычных устройств }
```

Чтобы добавить атрибут `open` используйте метод `document.getElementById(id вашего элемента <details>).setAttribute('open', '1')`

Comment: А если на странице много <details> и нужно всем добавить атрибут?

Comment: @Ярослав, getElementsByTagName('details') и setAttribute('open', '1') каждому в цикле.